# My implementation of mathematical formula returns different value than calculator

Tags: c++, function, math

```cpp
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEF
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    const double e = 2.71;
    double x, a, b, c, A, B, C, M;

    cout << "Enter the value of x, a, b and c:  ";
    cin >> x >> a >> b >> c;

    A = x + pow(sqrt(x + a), 3);
    // cout << A;
    B = x - sqrt((abs(x - b)));
    // cout << B;
    C = A / B;
    M = pow(e, -1 * c) * C;

    cout << "The result of function is " << M;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

For example, lets define *x=1*, *a=4*, *b=5*, *c=1*.
Calculator returns *M* as *-0.9547605358*, but code calculates `M` as `-4.49459`.

This is mathematical formula that I need to code:
[image]

Comment: `pow(sqrt(x + a), 3)` isn't the cube root of `x + a`. Using single letter identifiers with upper and lower case of the same letter is just asking for typos.

Comment: Also `_USE_MATH_DEF` and the macros it enables are not standard.  Better to avoid them.   You're only using it for `e` anyway.   Simply replace `pow(e, -1 * c)` by `exp(-c)`  (and correct it to `exp(-c*x)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I see some problems, namely `A` must be

```
A = x + pow(sqrt(x + a), 1.0/3.0);
```

`B` and `C` definition is correct, but `M` must be

```
M = pow(e, -1 * c * x) * C;
```

I would also like to point out that `conio.h` is a non standard header file and `_getch()` is non standard.